# Isotope data-filter not filtering after Ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-isotope

I want to have a filter that can be dynamically updated:

I used isotope javascript in an external script file:

```
    var $container = $('.isotope');
    // initialize isotope
    $container.isotope({
      // options...
    });

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('.filter a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
      $('.filter a.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      return false;
    });
```

And my filter links:

```
<ul class="filter clearfix" id="filterContainer">
    <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first link 'All' works but the problem comes when i tries to add more links into it using ajax:

```
    function getFilterHtml() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/getFilterHtml",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                //$("#filterContainer").html(msg.d);  
                var $newItems = $(msg.d);
                $('#filterContainer').append($newItems).isotope('addItems', $newItems).isotope('reLayout', callback).isotope('reloadItems');
            }
        });
    }
```

After the callback, this is how it looks like. Except that **When Phone Department is clicked, it brings me to the top of the page"**

```
    <ul id="filterContainer" class="filter clearfix">
        <li>
            <a class="active" data-filter="*" href="#">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-filter=".PhoneDepartment" href="#">Phone Department</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: reload the isotope function after ajax call completed

Comment: i've already reloaded it

Answer (score 2):

I've done the same thing using this code:

```
   $('#filterContainer').append($newItems).isotope('insert', $newItems);
```

without reLayout/reloadItems